# Python Websockets : infinite lock on client recv

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.6

I am learning how to use the `websockets` package for python 3.6 with `asyncio`.

Using the [Websockets Getting Started](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) example, here are my server and client code (both running in two separate console using `python <script>`)

wsserver.py

```
import asyncio

import websockets

msg_queue = asyncio.Queue()


async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    global msg_queue
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print("Received message {}".format(message))
        await msg_queue.put("Hello {}".format(message))
        print("Message queued")


async def producer_handler(websocket):
    global msg_queue
    while True:
        print("Waiting for message in queue")
        message = await msg_queue.get()
        print("Poped message {}".format(message))
        websocket.send(message)
        print("Message '{}' sent".format(message))


async def handler(websocket, path):
    print("Got a new connection...")
    consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(websocket))
    producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(websocket))

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([consumer_task, producer_task]
                                       , return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    print("Connection closed, canceling pending tasks")
    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()


start_server = websockets.serve(handler, 'localhost', 5555)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

---

wsclient.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def repl():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:5555') as websocket:
        while True:
            name = input("\nWhat's your name? ")

            await websocket.send(name)
            print("Message sent! Waiting for server answer")

            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            # never goes here
            print("> {}".format(greeting))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(repl())
```

---

During the execution, the server is doing what is expected of him :

- Wait for a client message
- Queue `'Hello $message'`
- Dequeue it
- Send the dequeued message back to the sender

The client does work up to the waiting of the server response :

- Wait for a user input
- Send it to the server
- Wait answer from the server  <-- Holds on indefinitely
- Print it & loop

Here are the console outputs of the execution :

Server

```
Got a new connection...
Waiting for message in queue
Received message TestName
Message queued
Poped message Hello TestName 
Message 'Hello TestName' sent 
Waiting for message in queue
```

Client

```
What's your name? TestName
Message sent! Waiting for server answer
_
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server-side, you're missing an `await` on the `websocket.send(message)` line.

To find those kind of bugs, start your program with the PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG environment variable, like: `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 python3 wsserver.py` which prints:

```
<CoroWrapper WebSocketCommonProtocol.send() running at […]/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py:301, created at wsserver.py:23> was never yielded from
```

Comment: After re-reading the doc examples and the [API specs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.send) , I noticed that the `send` function was a coroutine. Thank you!